# Jboss Configuration... Slow Page loads on application

Tags: jboss

I am deploying a custom java application to my jboss server... I am getting really really slow page loads (like 15 min) between pages.

Does anyone have any Jboss tips? tools to optimize Jboss? I am using the newest version of Jboss.

Thanks for your thoughts.

Jared

Answer (score 2):

Ok so I finally figured it out... in the Jboss settings file which is ../jboss-5.1.0.GA-src/build/output/jboss-5.1.0.GA/bin/run.conf you have to change the JAVA OPTS;

From:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-*Xms128m -Xmx512m* -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000"
```

To something like this:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-**Xms1024m -Xmx1024**m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000"
```

I hope that helps someone else out there.  My pages on my application are loading at 6 sec a pop compared to 10 minutes a page.

Answer (score 0):

You can slim down the JBoss server by removing components you do not need. I beleive that [JBoss in action](http://www.nerdbooks.com/item.php?id=1933988029) has a section on it.

Note: Examples in the book may not align perfectly with the version you downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting 15 minute response times, I don't think that optimizing jboss in general is going to solve your issues.  Try [something](http://www.javaperformancetuning.com/resources.shtml#ProfilingToolsFree) [like](http://www.javaperformancetuning.com/resources.shtml#ProfilingToolsNotFree) [jboss profiler](http://labs.jboss.com/jbossprofiler/) to see what's causing such slow page loads.